# Why Pandas Series resample function generated an unexpected start_time after resampling?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series data in pandas, I wanna calculate the number of data in different bins by using resampling function of pandas with a specified frequency.

The pandas series looks like something below if you use :

```
test_data.head(10)
```

You will get the results (only show top 10 data as it is a large Series):

```
    Created
2015-11-29 23:28:50    KBH889
2015-11-29 23:30:43    KBH89U
2015-11-29 23:34:06    KBH88K
2015-11-29 23:38:08    KBH8CC
2015-11-29 23:38:36    KBH83T
2015-11-29 23:40:52    KBH8CF
2015-11-29 23:46:27    KBH8F1
2015-11-29 23:50:01    KBH8DQ
2015-11-29 23:54:29    KBH8FV
2015-11-29 23:58:01    KBH8C6
Name: Order_Number, dtype: object
```

Then I use resample function with frequency "4541S" (It has to be 4541s exactly, cannot be changed!)

```
test_data.Order_Number.resample("4541S").count()
```

Results:

```
    Created
2015-11-29 22:42:18     9
2015-11-29 23:57:59    15
2015-11-30 01:13:40     6
2015-11-30 02:29:21     3
2015-11-30 03:45:02     2
Freq: 4541S, Name: Order_Number, dtype: int64
```

The resampled results starts with date time index `2015-11-29 22:42:18`. This is unwanted start_time. I want the time to be the minimal value of the series, in which case  the resampling should happen starting from `2015-11-29 23:28:50`. Does anybody know how to do this? I tried to use param `base` in the resampling function to adjust it. It seems it is difficult.

Here is the [csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ug1yllhajcp8eb5/test.csv?dl=0) for your testing. Import it and resample with count().

Comment: `count()` is returning a series? Is that right or did you add `.count()` by mistake on your question

Comment: I'm confused by your data types. How are you resampling a non-numeric column? Can you provide a .csv with your data?

Comment: @vmg: count() is used to count number of data sets with resampling. It did return a new binned time series. You can resample any column as long as your index is datetimeindex, I think

Comment: @vmg: I attached csv file. You can try my codes `test_data.resample("4541S").count()`

Comment: Ok, I get it now. I was curious how you were getting those results with `.count()` and the answer is the [resample API changed in pandas version 0.18](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0180-breaking-resample), which I was not familiar with. I am now able to replicate your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are correct in that this should be achieved with the `base` argument. Unfortunately, I also cannot find a way to easily anchor the resampling with the original first datetimeindex (in your case, '2015-11-29 23:28:50') instead of a calculated one ('2015-11-29 22:42:18').

As a workaround, which might be helpful in your case but not entirely useful for other cases, here's what you can do: get the 'original' datetimeindex from the original data and the 'calculated' first datetimeindex from the resampled data:

```
original = test_data.index[0]
calculated = test_data.Order_Number.resample('4541S',how='count',base=0).index[0]
```

(notice I am using pandas 0.17 resample API - you might need to apply `.count()` instead of using the 'how' argument)

Then get the difference in seconds between that 'calculated' first datetimeindex and the original first datetimeindex:

```
base_seconds = int((original - calculated).seconds)
```

And finally, use `base_seconds` as the value for the `base` argument:

```
test_data.Order_Number.resample('4541S',how='count',base=base_seconds)
```

Which yields

```
Created
2015-11-29 23:28:50    19
2015-11-30 00:44:31    10
2015-11-30 02:00:12     3
2015-11-30 03:15:53     3
Freq: 4541S, Name: Order_Number, dtype: int64
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. This is also the solution I found. Thanks! Hopefully pandas can release a better resample function with more clear base usage.